# Javascript wallet with ERC20 support

Tags: erc-20, javascript

I'm looking for a javascript wallet for Ethereum (like [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js) for example) with support for listing the ERC20 tokens that the wallet is holding and also being able to send them to other wallet addresses.

My understanding for the later, is that all I need is the Smart Contract ABI of the ERC20 token and its address. Is that correct?

Going with web3 is not an option since I can't run a full node on the server I'll deploy my code.